# Fill last spot of matrix with NA

Tags: r, matrix

I think I might be missing something very simply, but:

How I can I fill the last spots of a matrix with NA instead of it just repeating previous values?

Data example:

```
x <- 1:27
m <- matrix(x, nrow = 12, ncol = ceiling(nrow(base.de)/12), byrow = FALSE)

col_names <- c("2013", "2014", "2015")
row_names <- c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", 
             "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")

dimnames(m) <- list(row_names, col_names)
m

 2013 2014 2015
Jan    1   13   25
Feb    2   14   26
Mar    3   15   27
Apr    4   16    1 # NOT NA? 
May    5   17    2 
Jun    6   18    3 
Jul    7   19    4 
Aug    8   20    5 
Sep    9   21    6 
Oct   10   22    7 
Nov   11   23    8 
Dec   12   24    9
```

I would like all values after 2015 March to be filled with NA.

Comment: `m[28:length(m)] <- NA`? You can't avoid recycling of values.

Comment: Side note, there is a built in constant for month names: `month.abb`, `month.name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assign a shorter vector to a longer vector in R, it recycles the values in the shorter vector. That's what you are observing here. (Note that a matrix is just a vector with dimension attribute.) This behaviour cannot be avoided. So, you should assign `NA` after creating the matrix:

```
m[28:length(m)] <- NA
```

Or, alternatively, you could append the necessary number of `NA` values to `1:27` when creating the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Create a list of dimnames and from that create a matrix of NAs.  Finally, fill it:

```
x <- 1:27 # input as per question
dnm <- list(month.abb, 2013:2015) # list of dimnames

m <- matrix(NA, nrow = length(dnm[[1]]), ncol = length(dnm[[2]]), dimnames = dnm)
m[seq_along(x)] <- x
```

**Note:** You might not want to do this at all and instead create a monthly time series:

```
 library(zoo)
 z <- zooreg(x, as.yearmon("2013-01"), freq = 12)
```

giving:

```
> z
Jan 2013 Feb 2013 Mar 2013 Apr 2013 May 2013 Jun 2013 Jul 2013 Aug 2013 
       1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8 
Sep 2013 Oct 2013 Nov 2013 Dec 2013 Jan 2014 Feb 2014 Mar 2014 Apr 2014 
       9       10       11       12       13       14       15       16 
May 2014 Jun 2014 Jul 2014 Aug 2014 Sep 2014 Oct 2014 Nov 2014 Dec 2014 
      17       18       19       20       21       22       23       24 
Jan 2015 Feb 2015 Mar 2015 
      25       26       27
```

or a `ts` series:

```
> as.ts(z)
     Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
2013   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12
2014  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24
2015  25  26  27
```

or directly:

```
ts(x, start = c(2013, 1), freq = 12)
```